# Can Settings bundle use values from application's Info.plist file?

Tags: iphone, xcode

is it possible to use values from application's `Info.plist` file as `DefaultValue` value for items in Settings.bundle? For example `CFBundleVersion`. I've tried entering it as `${CFBundleVersion}` but it didn't work. I've also tried changing `DefaultValue` type but with no success. Any ideas?

The reasons behind are simple:

- `CFBundleVersion` is known at compile
  time, so I won't have to take its
  value from application's `mainBundle`
  and then apply that value to
  `NSUserDefaults`.
- Other reason is that just after
  installing the app, **but before
  running it**, Settings bundle values
  are not in-sync as the code setting
  `NSUserDefaults` did not have a
  chance to execute itself... so it would be
  boring to always remember that I have
  to change my Settings bundle values
  manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I synchronize my app's version to use in my Settings.bundle

```
[defaults setObject:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] forKey:@"kVersion"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I place that piece of code in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` app delegate, so every time the app launches it makes sure that the correct version is displayed in my Settings.bundle. This takes the app version value from your info.plist

Comment: @WrightCS: thanks, but it's not the answer I've been looking for :( I aim at using CFBundleVersion directly in Root.plist of Settings.bundle. A bit weird, I know, but need it.